# Change Linux 3.5.0 Kernel Task Scheduler

Tags: c, linux, kernel, task, scheduler

As a project in my operating systems class we have to modify the task scheduler and change the algorithm it is using to a custom (and rather dumb, such as going by highest PID) algorithm.  I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (server edition) on a virtual machine and am looking for the file that I would need to modify for this.  I have downloaded the open source version of the kernel and have not been able to find it.  Any help would be appreciated on finding the file where the scheduling algorithms are contained.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the schedulers in the Linux kernel source under `kernel/sched/`.

Comment: I have found the files and there is a lot of code to go through. Is there a way that I can create my own scheduler (similar to fair.c) in this directory and have it included when I recompile the kernel?

Comment: You can start by looking at the `sched_class` structure.